# React Function to Generate random name from Array error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-component

I'm getting an error with my component "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" from my RandomName component in my [react app](https://github.com/markohanesian/armenian-names) . What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function RandomName(props) {
    const [name, newName] = useState(0);

    const { names } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <button onClick={() => newName(names[Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)])}>
                New Name
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <RandomName names={['Paul', 'David', 'Kevin']} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

export default RandomName
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You literally posted the answer to your own question, before the question: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".  `names` is `undefined`.

Comment: `names` is number. You can't find its length

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an array first and then you use [faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker) to put fake names in it.

```
const a = new Array(50).fill(null)
                       .map(e =>
                   e = faker.fake("{{name.lastName}}, {{name.firstName}}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code above seems to be correct but instead of 0 you can pass ''. But from Github repo I noticed you are not passing names in App.js.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/">
            <>
              <RandomName names={['Paul', 'David', 'Kevin']} />
            </>
         </Route>
</Switch>
```

[Updated Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-meadow-uodsq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways

> use typescript to check props data type

```
function RandomName({names=[]}:{names:Array<string>}){...}
```

> use below code for check propTypes

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
.
.
.
RandomName .propTypes = {
names: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
}
```

> and use below code to define function

```
function RandomName({names=[],...restprops}){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the component working like so - thank you all for your help:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

import './index.css'

const names=['Mark', 'Steve', 'Tom']

function RandomName() {
const [name, newName] = useState('Bob');

```
return (
    <div id="RandomName-container">
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => newName(names[Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)])}>
            New Name
        </button>
    </div>
);
```

}

export default RandomName